# Using VBA to perform Vlookup on an external workbook from Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I can't get an external workbook to use Vlookup to return the value of a different column.

I am trying to take a word document, enter an ID number into a text box, have vlookup find the ID number in an external document then return a name from the next column. Then the name will populate a different textbox and the date the number was entered will go in a third box. Right now EMPID.txt has only two columns A: EmpNum and B: EmpName.

```
Private Sub VerID_LostFocus()

    Dim emp_number As String
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Workbook

    Set xlApp = Excel.Workbooks.Open("filepath\EmpID.xlsx")

    emp_number = VerID.Text

    MsgBox emp_number

    On Error Resume Next

    result = Excel.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(emp_number, xlApp.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:B"), 2, False)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If result <> "" Then MsgBox result

    MsgBox result

    VerSig.Text = result

    Set xlApp = Nothing

    VerDate.Value = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")

End Sub
```

emp_number get assigned and shows as the value in a message box but nothing gets returned or assigned to result. The date is updated in the third textbox anytime the first "lost focus".

Comment: Comment out/remove the `On Error Resume Next`. Does it throw an error?

Answer (score 0):

`WorksheetFunction` works with Application Object, Since You already declared `XlApp` as Workbook change the line to

```
Result = xlApp.Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(emp_number, Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:B"), 2, False)
```

and it is working. Also  if  `emp_number`is entered as Number in the workbook, then make the following changes

```
Dim emp_number As Variant 
'
'
'
'
emp_number = Val(VerID.Text)
```

Comment: That did it!  Thanks a lot for the assistance!